# How to deploy EAR into web configuration in JBoss?

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

We use **"web"** configuration of JBoss.
Now we deploy **war** files only.
But we are going to deploy **ear** to JBoss.
As far as I can see it is impossible to deploy **ear** on **web** configuration because there is ***no ear deployer in web configuration***.
Will it be enough just to copy file **default\deployers\ear-deployer-jboss-beans.xml** to **web\deployers** directory?
Or some additional files should be copied too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of starting with the web configuration I will suggest to use the "default" configuration and trim it. For example, remove JMS.

Comment: We already trimmed web configuration :) But now we need to use ear.

Comment: @Vladimir Bezugliy, yeah I know. I tried in the past to enhance the web configuration with ear support without succeeding. Finally, we decided to trim the ear. Please let us know if you manage to enhance the web configuration with ear.

Comment: +1 It will be much easier to trim the `default` configuration than try to add stuff to the `web` configuration.